# How to stick custom header in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on app where I have worked on app header . I have created custom component for header . Now I want to achieve stick header when user scroll down then I want to stick top header . Could someone please help me how to solve this issue .

**Code**

```
      <View>
        <Header navigation={navigation} newToken={this.state.token} />
        <SearchBar
          input={(value) => {
            this.onChangeTextDelayed(value);
            this.setState({
              subCategoriesShow: true,
              pharmLoader: true,
              inputValue: value,
              queries: [],
            });
          }}
          handleBlur={() => this.setState({ subCategoriesShow: false })}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by view and a scroll view.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, display: 'flex'}}>
    <View>
        <Header {...props}/>
    </View>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        ... other things
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

If this doesn't work you can try with

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
```

instead of

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
```

Comment: I just want to stick header , I have other contents too . I want to be stick up with header

Comment: @Jonas Maybe there is an issue with your container components. There is a working snack example https://snack.expo.io/JW7y!BQR_